# Generate URL for different subdomains in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am having a website and its admin panel in one Laravel application. I have a sub-domain routing for admin routes, and the default routes are applied to website.

The thing I need is to generate route for website in admin panel. Think like creating a post in admin panel, and then having a "preview" link in list of posts to view the post in website. How can I do that?

I am currently generating URLs in admin panel using `route` function, and the replacing admin sub-domain with website domain. It is somehow hackish and I don't like it.

So, TLDR, how to make this generate a URL for a specific domain:

`route('route.name', $data)`

Answer (score -1):

I hope I understand your problem correctly! but laravel handle subdomain routing in this way:

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.example.com')->group(function () {
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($subdomain, $id) {
    //
});
```

});

and make sure you've added subdomain to your web service (nginx/apache)

did you do it like this?

Comment: I would take this approach ^   you can split all requests by subdomains. You can also take it 1 step further and use a config file to ``` config('app.my_admin_domain') and config('app.url')  and use those in your domain

Comment: I'm sure both of you did not even finish reading the question properly. The question is about generating URLs, not sub-domain routing.